# Swift. Collection of inherited objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I have class Fruit as base class. I created 2 other classes which inherited from Fruit: Apple and Orange.

I need to add Apples and Oranges in array. I want to have Fruit class of that array. Is it possible?

And if so, how can I read items from that array and define class of it.

Sample:

```
var ar: [Fruit] = [Apple, Apple, Orange] 

for i in ar {
    if i is Apple {
    ...
    } else if i is Orange {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's reasonable to tag a question "swift" and then "swift[some version]", but Swift 2 and Swift 3 are different enough that you should probably pick just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this

```
class Fruit { }
class Apple: Fruit { }
class Orange: Fruit { }
```

You can create an array if `Fruit(s)`

```
var fruits: [Fruit] = []
```

You can add an Apple

```
fruits.append(Apple())
```

or an Orange

```
fruits.append(Orange())
```

### Iterating the fruits

```
for fruit in fruits {
    switch fruit {
    case let apple as Apple: print(apple)
    case let orange as Orange: print(orange)
    default: print("Another fruit")
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I go throught array and define class of items?